# ActiveRecord : Cannot modify association because it goes through more than one other association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm not sure why this association is invalid

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :routes
end

class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :super_route
 has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class SuperRoute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :route
  has_many :tags, through: :route
end
```

Then I'd expect to be able to do the following

```
s = SuperRoute.create
s.route = Route.create
s.tags << Tag.create
```

except this throws the error

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly: Cannot modify association 'SuperRoute#tags' because it goes through more than one other association.
```

What is the fundamental error here?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SuperRoute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :route
  has_many :tags     #remove through: :route
end
```

Comment: This implies a foreign key relationship between the SuperRoute and Tag classes, which is specifically what I'm trying to avoid.